# Why there is Difference between shapes of ROC of z domain and s domain?

Tags: z-transform, laplace-transform

ROC(region of convergence) of Z domain is shown by a circular region while ROC in S domain is shown by a rectangular(approximately looking like rectangle) region

What is the reason of this difference in shapes of ROC regions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, the region of convergence in the Laplace transform 
$$
X(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-st} dt 
$$ 
is related to the weighting provided by the real part of the complex $s = \sigma + j \omega$; as this will yield the weight $|e^{-st}| =  e^{-\sigma t}$  applied on the input signal $x(t)$, and is a function of $\sigma$ alone and is a **rectangular** (planar) region on the s-plane.

But the region of convergence in the Z-transform 
$$
X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] z^{-n}
$$
is related to the weighting provided by the **magnitude** of the complex $z = \sigma + j \omega$ as given by $|z|^{-n} = |\sigma + j\omega|^{-n} = |z|^{-n} |e^{-j n \angle{z}}| = |z|^{-n}$, which is a **circular** region on th z-plane, due to the magnitude of $z$ being involved.